# "~holic" or "~aholic"? Which one could be the most appropriate?

Tags: slang, non-standard

I've heard words like bookaholic, workaholic, etc., but why the 'a' before them?
On the other hand, I've also discovered Asian bands, songs or other stuff with names like Swing-Holic, Sound-Holic, etc., and those seem even more coherent.

Both cases are emerging terms by some common semantic association considering the first historical spread use and lose of control over alcohol consumption. Maybe someone can give a rule for those suffixes.

Comment: *Logical reasoning*? What has that to do with the English language?

Comment: None of them make sense, unless you're addicted to workahol/workohol/workhol, bookahol/bookohol/bookhol, or soundahol/soundohol/soundhol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically it most likely stems from the word "Alcoholic" which is quite a common word. Even though it's actually pronounced "*Al-Ko-Hall-Ik*" people (including myself) when talking fast say it as "*Al-Ka-Hall-Ik*". When creating new terms people match the words to how they will say it, with the "*-A-Hall-Ik*" transferring.

A more common example of this is the word "Illegal". Some people say "*EE-Legal*" but it's pronounced how it looks: "*Ill-Legal*". Same thing with "Refinance". I can't stand it when radio ad people say "*Re-Fin-nance*". It's pronounced like "*Re-Fine-nance*".

It also sounds cleaner. Bookholic does not roll off of the tongue as well as Bookaholic.

EDIT: There's a Wiktionary article [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-holic) for the suffix. I saw this after I posted this. It pretty much says what I say above, listing "*-aholic*" and "*-oholic*" as alternate forms.

Comment: There are many ways to pronounce English words. Much as I like to think of my own way as "right", it doesn't *actually* make other pronunciations wrong.

Comment: @AndyT I generally just stick to the dictionary pronunciation of Websters or  Google.

Answer (score 1):

According to Etymonline the suffix ***[-oholic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=holic)*** has been gradually replaced by ***-aholic*** in new words formation like *shopaholic or golfaholic:*

> - word-forming element abstracted from alcoholic (q.v.); also see -aholic, which has tended to replace it in word formation.

***[-aholic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-aholic&allowed_in_frame=0)***:

> - word-forming element abstracted from alcoholic; first in sugarholic (1965), foodoholic (sic., 1965); later in workaholic (1968), golfaholic (1971), chocoholic (1971), and shopaholic (1984).